# Setting [BindNever] during the action execution filter flow

Tags: filter, binding, asp.net-core-mvc

Does anyone know how I can mark an argument on `ActionDescriptor.Parameters` to behave in a similar way the [BindNever] is behaving?

I want to always exclude a specific argument from a specific type without keep decorating it on the Controller.

Essentially I would like to be able to add my injected to my functions somehow how similar to the way its done with CancellationToken

```html
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet(Name = "Get")]
        public IActionResult Get([BindNever] IInjectedInterface injected)
        {
            //Injected can be used in this method

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "Post")]
        public IActionResult Post([BindNever] IInjectedInterface injected, FormModel formModel)
        {
            //Injected doesn't work here. There is an error that 

            /*System.InvalidOperationException: 'Action 'WebApplication3.Controllers.TestController.Post (WebApplication3)'
             has more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from request body. Only one parameter per action may be bound from body. 
            Inspect the following parameters, and use 'FromQueryAttribute' to specify bound from query, 'FromRouteAttribute' to specify bound from route, 
            and 'FromBodyAttribute' for parameters to be bound from body:
            IInjectedInterface injected
            FormModel formModel'
            */

            return Ok();
        }
    }



public class ActionExecutionFilter : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var injectedParam = context.ActionDescriptor.Parameters.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ParameterType == typeof(IInjectedInterface));
        if (injectedParam != null)
        {
            context.ActionArguments[injectedParam.Name] = new Injected(99);
        }

        await next.Invoke();
    }

    private class Injected : IInjectedInterface
    {
        public Injected(int someData)
        {
            SomeData = someData;
        }

        public int SomeData { get; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some codes to explain more details about which argument you want to exclude?

Comment: I updated the post. thx for your support

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it. Apparently you need to add the following lines on your program.cs to avoid the model binder related errors.

```
options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(
    new ExcludeBindingMetadataProvider(typeof(IInjectedInterface)));

options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(
    new BindingSourceMetadataProvider(typeof(IInjectedInterface), BindingSource.Special));
```